# Why the @keyfame animation property tricking down to below list item? I want to delete a list item to be deleted upon button click using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code - on clicking the button, my requirement is to delete the corresponding list item from the list panel and also from the current state.

```
    <style>
        @keyframes deleting{
            0%{
                opacity: 1;
            }
            25%{
                opacity: .60;
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }
            50%{
                opacity: .30;
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }
            100%{
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
        .task-done {
            animation-name: deleting;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-duration: .5s;
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
        body{
            text-align: center;            
        }
        input, button{
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        li{
            font-size: 25px;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        .no-bullets{
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="task"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        class App extends React.Component {

            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    tasks : [],
                    input : ""
                }
            }
            render(){

                let taskList;
                if(this.state.tasks.length <= 0){
                    taskList = <h2 id="no-task">Hurrah! You can take a break</h2>
                }else{
                    taskList = 
                            <div>
                                <h2><i>You have {this.state.tasks.length} task(s) pending:</i></h2>
                                    <ul className="no-bullets">
                                        {this.state.tasks.map((task, i) =>
                                            <li key={i} className="task-done" data-index={i}>
                                                <button className="material-icons button" onClick={this.taskComplete}>
                                                done_outline</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;{task}
                                            </li>
                                        )}
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                }

            return(
                <div>                                    
                    <div>
                        <h1>Task Manager</h1>                        
                        <input type="text" onChange = {this.handleInput} placeholder = "Enter a task" value = {this.state.input}/>
                        <button onClick = {this.addTask}>Add Task</button>                
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {taskList}
                    </div>                         


                </div>

            );
        }


        handleInput = event => {
            this.setState({
                input : event.target.value
            });
        }

        addTask = () =>{
            if(this.state.input.length > 0){
                this.setState(state => ({
                    tasks : [...state.tasks, state.input],
                    input : ""
                }));
            }
        }

        taskComplete = event => {
            const element = event.target;

            element.parentElement.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
            element.parentElement.addEventListener('animationend', () =>  {

            const index = element.parentElement.getAttribute("data-index");

            let tempList = [...this.state.tasks];
            tempList.splice(index, 1);

            this.setState(state => ({
                tasks : [...tempList]
            }));


            });


        }
    }

        ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#task"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When selecting first item on the list, it is deleting the first item as intended, but @keyframe property also added to 2nd item, and its opacity set to 0.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably use some other `key` value for `li` which doesn't depend on index. Since you are mutating the list, index is not a good candidate for key.

A `key` is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in the middle? If the `key` is same as before React assumes that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that is no longer true.

Refer to this article for more information:-
https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318